# Rotate an image with crop

Tags: java, rotation, transform

I have an image with a softcrop.

i.e 
The image bounds are width 3 and height 5.
In the image I have a soft crop at (x,y) 1,4 and bounds width 1 and height 1.

How can I get the new position (x,y) for the crop after I rotate the image 90 degrees?

AffineTransform perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use AffineTransform.

You can use AffineTransform.getRotateInstance and AffineTransform#transform(Point2D, Point2D).

Use it like so:

```
AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 2.0, width / 2.0, height / 2.0);
Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(1, 4);
Point2D.Double result = new Point2D.Double();
transform.transform(point, result);
```

Please note that the top left point of the soft crop area will no longer be the top left point after rotation but the bottom left.

Comment: Did make two mistakes in the code above. Had minus signs in front of width and height and did use Math.PI instead of Math.PI / 2.0. Corrected now, so if you already tried this you may do again.